# I Can't understand why I'm not being able to use pycoin package in my python project, even it being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, package

So, I'm trying to this this imports:

```
from pycoin.ecdsa import generator_secp256k1, sign, verify
```

But I always get this error:

```
Unresolved reference 'pycoin'
```

The thing is, pycoin is already installed in my machine so I can't understand why it isn't working...the IDE offers me the opportunity to install the package, since it doesn't recognize it, but still, I receive this error after the attempt of installation:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/218/plugins/python/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util
```

This is what I receive when I try to install pycoin again with the comand line:

```
➜ sudo python3 -m pip install pycoin
[sudo] password for pedro: 
Requirement already satisfied: pycoin in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.90.20200809)
```

So it is installed, I just can't figure it out why it is not working...

Comment: For that second error, see https://askubuntu.com/q/1239829.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `sudo python3 -m pip install pycoin` you are seeing it installed into python3.8 but when you run it in the IDE it's attempting to install it on python3.6. So yes, it's installed, but you have multiple distributions of python.

To fix the python 3.6 issue, search `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util` there are answers on fixing it.